# Как сделать фон у кнопок-переключателей

Tags: android, button

Доброго времени суток, [RU stackOverFlow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) !

Необходимо скруглить углы у кнопки, но не прибегая к статическому назначению через разметку xml.

Идея следующая:

- имеется две кнопки, реализующие обратные друг другу действия;
- если нажать первую, то она подсвечивается/заливается синим цветом, а вторая становится белой. При нажатии на вторую процесс/алгоритм обратный.

Задал в xml скругление, все работает, но при смене цвета через `setBackground` заливается кнопка с прямыми углами, а скргуление через xml затирается.

Нашел в инете способ:

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryColor));
gd.setCornerRadius(10);
gd.setStroke(2, getResources().getColor(R.color.myBorderColor));
btnCheckAll.setBackground(gd);
```

но компилятор подсвечивает ошибку на `setBackground` и говорит, что данная возможность есть только на API16+, а минималка стоит API14. Да, приложение пишу с расчетом на смартфоны с API14 и выше.
(запустилось на реальном устройстве с API16).

Как правильно переписать данный код или какой иной использовать в моем случае ?

Comment: А эти ваши кнопки, они как на разметке относительно друг друга расположены?

Comment: @pavlofff, рядом в одном слое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ваши кнопки можно расположить относительно друг друга с помощью `LinearLayout`, то имеет смысл для такой функциональности использовать `RadioGroup` (он наследник `LinearLayout`и позволяет компоновать элементы внутри по тем же принципам) - это даст несколько полезных возможностей для управления блоком и автоматическое переключение кнопок в блоке :

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/groupButton">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_background"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_background"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Button 2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Если кнопке требуется иконка, то ее можно добавить в свойства `RadioButton`, используя атрибуты `android:drawableRight` - справа, `android:drawableLeft`-слева и тд. , кроме того, вы можете использовать атрибут `android:button` для размещения иконки слева, а используя селектор можно менять вид этой иконки в зависимости от состояний виджета (вместо `"@android:color/transparent"`):

```
<RadioButton
        android:button="@drawable/left_image"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_image" />
```

Вид включенного\выключенного  `RadioButton` можно задать, ограничиваясь только своей фантазией.  Например, прямоугольники со скругленными углами.

**radio_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="6dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#1381ff" />
            <solid android:color="#2d4bcc" />
            <padding android:left="10dp"
             android:top="4dp"
             android:right="10dp"
             android:bottom="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="6dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#1381ff" />
            <solid android:color="#2d4bcc" />
            <padding android:left="10dp"
             android:top="4dp"
             android:right="10dp"
             android:bottom="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="6dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#2d4bcc" />
            <solid android:color="#1381ff" />
            <padding android:left="10dp"
             android:top="4dp"
             android:right="10dp"
             android:bottom="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Прослушивает события такой группы колбэк `OnCheckedChangeListener()`, причем параметром служит вся группа, а не отдельные элементы, то есть не нужно вешать слушатель на каждую кнопку:

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.groupButton);

group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            switch (checkedId) {
            case -1:
                // Ничего не выбрано
                break;
            case R.id.button1:
                // выбрана кнопка 1
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                // выбрана кнопка 2
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
```

[Больше о возможностях `RadioGroup`](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/radiobutton.php)

Если ваши кнопки нельзя скомпоновать в один `GadioGroup`, то используйте отдельные `RadioButton` т.к. они позволяют сохранять положение checked/unchecked , хотя часть удобств,вроде автоматического переключения будет потеряна.

Так же возможно кастомизировать другие виджеты, реализующие интерфейс `Checkable` (`Checkbox`,`ToggleButton` - их вид можно задать,ограничиваясь только вашей фантазией) , если их логика больше подходит для ваших задач, но простые кнопки для такой функциональности подходят наименее всего.

Comment: Да, Ваш ответ практичнее решения с двумя кнопками. Спасибо.

Comment: могу я на каждую из кнопок повесить отдельную иконку ?

Comment: @web_alex добавил в ответ про иконки. Почитайте по ссылке в ответе, там можно узнать много интересного по этой теме

Comment: я уже добавил их и забыл отписаться сюда. Спасибо за дополнение ответа. Пускай остается, думаю, что более раскрытый ответ пригодится еще не малому количеству гуглистов.

Answer (score 2):

Есть устаревший метод-аналог **setBackgroundDrawable()**. Код [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11947755/3212712).

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
{
    setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
} 
else 
{
    setBackground(gd);
}
```