# Mini color picker для быстрого выбора цвета из нескольких вариантов

Tags: android, checkbox, color

В приложении (minSdkLevel=9) хочется предложить пользователям возможность для быстрой смены основного цвета.

Что-то вроде цветных check box в нижней строке данного рисунка:

[image: mini color picker]

Поиск среди библиотек на GitHub пока ничего не принес.

Поиск на Stackoverflow показал как делать разноцветные галочки, но они несимпатично выглядят.

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой и нашел удачное решение для быстрого выбора цвета в одной строке?

Comment: Если проблема только во внешнем виде, то он может быть абсолютно любым, для [любых типов виджетов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345), например [чекбокса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419828/177345). Насчет библиотеки - не думаю, что такая есть, слишком простая функциональность для библиотеки. Так же сюда так и [напрашивается RadioGroup](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427583/177345)

Comment: могу поделится пикером как на этом видео: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYjC9Bm3eVk

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin я так понял из вопроса, что нужен не полноценный пикер ( каких много на том же github), а больше селектор для нескольких, заранее определенных, вариантов.

Comment: Да, ищу color-picker покомпактнее и из небольшой палитры цветов (потому что не хочу чтобы пользователь выбрал какие-нибудь невозможные цвета с которым приложением будет трудно пользоваться)

Comment: Скажите, какой внешний вид вы себе примерно представляете, может есть какой то макет?

Comment: Я нарисовал этот вариант наверху (см. нижнюю строку в скриншоте)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давным давно тоже искал решение такой задачи. В итоге сделал свой класс-палитру

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Pallet {

    private String color;

    public Pallet(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Pallet> getPallet(){
        ArrayList<Pallet> pallets = new ArrayList<>();
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#000000"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#404040"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#FF0000"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#FF6A00"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#FFD800"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#B6FF00"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#4CFF00"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#00FF21"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#00FF90"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#00FFFF"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#0094FF"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#0026FF"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#4800FF"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#B200FF"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#FF00DC"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#FF006E"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#FFFFFF"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#808080"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#7F0000"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#7F3300"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#7F6A00"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#5B7F00"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#267F00"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#007F0E"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#007F46"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#007F7F"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#004A7F"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#00137F"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#21007F"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#57007F"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#7F006E"));
        pallets.add(new Pallet("#7F0037"));

        return pallets;
    }
}
```

Вот его адаптер

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.fourstore.R;

import java.util.List;

public class PalletAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Pallet> pallets;
    private Context context;

    public PalletAdapter(Context context, List<Pallet> pallets) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pallets = pallets;
    }


    public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView color;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pallets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View customView = convertView;
        final Pallet pallet = pallets.get(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            customView = li.inflate(R.layout.pallet_item, null);
            holder.color = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.color);
            customView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) customView.getTag();
        }

        holder.color.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(pallet.getColor()));

        return customView;

    }


}
```

Его разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Разметка с GridView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/palletGridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:columnWidth="45dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Ну и собственно вызывается так

```
GridView palletGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.palletGridView);
    final ArrayList<Pallet> pallets = Pallet.getPallet();
    PalletAdapter palletAdapter = new PalletAdapter(self, pallets);
    palletGridView.setAdapter(palletAdapter);

palletGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            UserSettings.set(UserSettings.TEXT_COLOR, pallets.get(position).getColor(), self);
});
```

Получится, примерно так, как Вы хотите. Цвета будут как в paint-е.

Comment: а нафига вот это ? pallets.add(new Pallet("#000000")); почему не просто pallets.add("#000000"); зачем делать класс из одной строки ?

Comment: Согласен. Здесь можно и так. Просто у меня он более расширен, и для примера я убрал все лишнее